# Passing variable from controller to view not working codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I been searching this issue all over the internet but I can't seem to find a good answer. I'm using codeigniter framework Version 2.1.4.

I have model: company.php and tbl_name: company

```
<?php
class Company extends CI_Model 
{
    public  function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }


    public function getCompany(){

    $q = $this->db->get('company');

        if($q->num_rows() > 0)
        {
          foreach ($q->result() as $row)
          {
            $data[] = $row;
          }
          return $data;
        }
    }

}
```

I have controller: home.php where I can call up the model I created.

```
public function getAll(){
    $this->load->model('company');
    $data['results'] = $this->company->getCompany();
    $this->load->view('branch', $data);
}
```

lastly I have view: branch.php where I can view data from DB

```
<?php

if(!empty($results))
    {

      foreach($results as $res) 
      {
        echo "Name: ".$res->company;
      }
    } 
 ?>
```

Now this is the problem: When I browse controller localhost/app/home/getAll, It works fine because I can see the data from database example: Name: ABC Company, but when I browse the views localhost/app/home/branch I get this error below.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: results

Filename: views/branch.php

Line Number: 11
1
```

Can you please help me? thanks

Comment: you code that gets the data from the db, is inside the getAll() method. Why do you expect it to be run when you visit some other route? Please add your home/branch thingy controller method

Comment: np. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like method getall() you should have method branch in same controller.

```
    public function getAll(){
        $this->load->model('company');
        $data['results'] = $this->company->getCompany();
        $this->load->view('branch', $data);
    } 

    public function branch(){
        $this->load->model('company');
        $data['results'] = $this->company->getCompany();
        $this->load->view('branch', $data);
   }
```

The error is because you are not passing data['result'] to view.

Comment: i have read the article about how to pass data From Controller To View In CodeIgniter 
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-pass-data-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if(isset($results))
```

instead of:

```
if(!empty($results))
```

In your view, branch.php

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->load->view('branch', array('data' => $data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this alternative way

Change your company model to :

```
public function getCompany(){

   $q = $this->db->get('company');

    return $q->result_array();
}
```

Change your view to :

```
foreach($results as $res) 
  {
    echo "Name: ".$res['company'];
  }
```

OR

Change your company model to :

```
public function getCompany(){

   $q = $this->db->get('company');

    return $q->result();
}
```

Change your view to :

```
foreach($results as $res) 
  {
    echo "Name: ".$res->company;
  }
```